# How can I get SLI working with 295.40?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I've been doing a lot of googling these last few hours and I'm not having much luck.  Perhaps I don't know exactly what I am looking for.

I just recently installed Ubuntu 12.04LTS x86_64.  Looks beautiful!

I have two GTX470's in SLI, and I am finally migrating my desktop over given the hopeful gaming support as of late.  My laptop has been enjoying multiple distros of Ubuntu for a couple years now.  However, new problems come with unexplored territory, here.

At first, I only had one working monitor of my two.  Over on nvidia-xconfig I fixed that, but the only solution that actually worked was twinview.  Just recently I read here that twinview is **not** compatible with SLI.  Sweet.

When I try to tell it, oh hey, use a separate XScreen, configure it the way I want it, click save to configuration file, enter my password, then a sudo restart lightdm, it's broken.  One screen blacks or whites out (Couldn't tell you the specific conditions for each, I'm dubious at this point,) and I get this **huge** error dialogue box upon login.  Something about incompatible resolutions if I remember right.  Though I am sure I set the resolutions for each screen correctly.

Anyway, when I try to enable SLI (sudo nvidia-xconfig --sli=On) despite the fact it hates twinview, unity breaks.  The sidebar is there, but only one screen works, the mouse is trapped running along the left edge of it, and the background of the sidebar is a solid blue.

Anyway, this ended up being entirely too verbose, I'm sorry, but could anyone part some wisdom please?  It would be appreciated!

Going to update, here.
I have done a lot of tinkering over the past couple hours and the only way I can have two monitors working, let alone SLI, is by using twinview.  I am starting to wonder if it is a known incompatibility to do so.  Is it even possible to have SLI on Ubuntu 12.04LTS with two active monitors?

Whenever I create separate screens instead of twinview, the second screen refuses to display unless I enable Xinerama.  If I enable Xinerama, however, both monitors display but the unity desktop refuses to load.  I login, it shows my background, and then nothing.

Here is my current working configuration:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 295.33  (buildd@allspice)  Fri Mar 30 15:25:24 UTC 2012


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"

    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VW266H"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 85.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 470"
    BusID          "PCI:2:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"

# Removed Option "TwinView" "0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
# Removed Option "metamodes" "DFP-1: 1920x1080_60 +0+0, DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0; DFP-1: nvidia-auto-select +0+0, DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "1"
    Option         "TwinViewXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP-0: 1920x1200_60 +1920+0, DFP-1: 1920x1080_60 +0+0; DFP-0: nvidia-auto-select +1920+0, DFP-1: 1920x1080_60 +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

**I recently read the FAQ for this website.**  I'm starting to think this belongs in a forum instead, feedback on this would be appreciated. There is a short story worth of text here, but I don't know well enough to judge.

All I really know is my eyes hurt and I need a smoke.